# What free JS library similar to PeerCDN I can use?

Tags: open-source, web-development, programming

[PeerCDN](https://peercdn.com/) was bought by Yahoo, I don't know where to download it or even if it has support on open source version (if there is any), I am looking for some js library implementing the same concept (using WebRTC data channels to deliver static content from browser to browser to reduce to load over main cdn servers)

The site of peerCDN list the features I need (and a little more), so, I only need a subset of this features, like:

- Allowing the browser download STATIC assets (e.g. HTML, CSS, JS, images, video and any content the browser need to download to display the webpage) from other browsers by using WebRTC decreasing the load on main CDN server
- Automatic fallback to traditional client-server CDN scheme if there is no chance to download the content from other browsers and/or webRTC is not supported
- (Optional) Transparency on implementation, only by loading the JS the library do his magic, I dont want to refactor all the webpage/app in order to include this

peercdn used to have all these feature and more, but I need only these

Comment: Thanks! As I even had to look up what a CDN is supposed to do, I cannot say if more is needed (let alone answer your question) – so all I can do now is wish you good luck! The additional details should make it easier for potential answerers at least.

Answer (score 2):

PeerCDN was acquired by Yahoo and then they shut them down. One of the creator's of peercdn started a project called http://webtorrent.io that he claims can be modified to do what you need to do. I myself was excited for peercdn and looking at swarmify (charging for bandwidth for some reason?) I'm not satisfied with their offer

Comment: Thanks!, that is the kind of answer I am looking for. But additional info for alternatives would be welcome too :)

Comment: The only other alternative I've found was swarmify